# Do I really need to track my carbs and fat if I'm hitting my daily calorie and protein numbers?

Tags: weight-loss, nutrition, muscle-gain, protein, carbohydrate

I have about a month of training experience and I'm currently on a cut (I consume 500 calories less than my TDEE). Since I'm aiming for body recomposition while maximizing my newbie gains.

My daily caloric intake is approximately 1800 calories with approximately 150gm protein (600 calories).
I'm okay with tracking my protein and my calories but it feels like a chore to track my carbs and fat (mainly because they don't really have that big of a role to play in recomp).
I know that fat is necessary for your bones and hormonal levels so I make sure to eat 25+gm fat everyday but after that I don't really count.

Is this acceptable? Or do I really need to maintain that perfect balance between all 3 macros?

Comment: Weight/Height/Age? How many meals a day?  What type of training? Are you a brain worker? Generally, you don't have to be too meticulous (for a newbie). Human body is not a machine. [See this](https://health.gov/our-work/food-nutrition/2015-2020-dietary-guidelines/guidelines/appendix-2/#:~:text=The%20reference%20woman%20is%205,per%20day%20for%20adult%20men.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you don't.
It won't affect body composition in any serious fashion.

Comment: It might not have any direct impact on body composition, but it will likely impact training (which can indirectly impact body composition). However, if no issues seem to be going on, there wouldn’t appear to be any reason to change.

Answer (score 4):

None of this is necessary. Plenty of people just "eat food, a lot of it, mostly protein" (to repurpose Michael Pollan) and find that plenty to fuel a heavy lifting regimen or strength & conditioning program. As long as you're roughly cognizant enough of all three macros such that you don't become tremendously unbalanced, you don't have to track carbs, fat, or anything else specifically.